# How to paginate and parse multiple pages concurrently on Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, parallel-processing, pagination, scrapy

I am trying to web-scrape multiple pages from a real estate website. I have been successful in scraping the first page of my URL, but unable to handle pagination. I have attempted trying to find a class tag with 'red' in it and identify next sibling. I believe this will get the next page response, and continue doing over and over. I read some examples were people wrote their code to be able to parse multiple pages at the same time.

Is it possible to do parallel/concurrent parsing? I want to be able to parse 90 pages as fast as possible, but don't know how to implement it. Any and all appreciated is greatly and much appreciated. Thank you.

**PROGRESS UPDATE 1:**
I figured out why my CSV outputs UTF-8 and returns Cyrillic characters correctly in my Pycharm IDE, but returns ?? placeholders when I use Excel. I have been able to bypass this issue by importing CSV file through Excel Data>From Text/CSV.

**PROGRESS UPDATE 2:** I understand I could implement a for loop in my start_request function and loop pages (1,90) or even (1,120) but that is not what I want, and this would make it so my code parses page by page, rather than concurrently.

**HTML Snippet:**

```html
<ul class="number-list">
  <li>
    <a href="/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/ulan-bator/?cities=1" class="page-number js-page-filter red" data-page="1">1</a>
  </li>
 
  <li>
    <a href="/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/ulan-bator/?cities=1&amp;page=2" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="2">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/ulan-bator/?cities=1&amp;page=3" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="3">3</a>
  </li>
  <li><span class="page-number">...</span></li>
  <li>
    <a href="/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/ulan-bator/?cities=1&amp;page=89" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="89">89</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/ulan-bator/?cities=1&amp;page=90" class="page-number js-page-filter " data-page="90">90</a>
  </li>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

**Pagination Snippet:**

```
# handling pagination
next_page = response.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'red')]/parent::li/following-sibling::li/a/@href").extract_first()
if next_page:
    yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

**Full Code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
import unicodecsv as csv
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

dt_today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
file_name = dt_today+' HPI Data'


# Create Spider class
class UneguiApartments(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "unegui_apts"
    allowed_domains = ["www.unegui.mn"]
    custom_settings = {"FEEDS": {f'{file_name}.csv': {'format': 'csv'}}
                       }

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/ulan-bator/']
        for url in urls:
            yield Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        cards = response.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'announcement-container')]")

        # parse details
        for card in cards:
            name = card.xpath(".//a[@itemprop='name']/@content").extract_first()
            price = card.xpath(".//*[@itemprop='price']/@content").extract_first()
            rooms = card.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'announcement-block__breadcrumbs')]/text()").extract_first().split('»')[0].strip()
            link = card.xpath(".//a[@itemprop='url']/@href").extract_first()
            date_block = card.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'announcement-block__date')]/text())").extract_first().split(',')
            date = date_block[0].strip()
            city = date_block[1].strip()

            item = {'name': name,
                    'date': date,
                    'rooms': rooms,
                    'price': price,
                    'city': city,
                    }
            # follow absolute link to scrape deeper level
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # retrieve previously scraped item between callbacks
        item = response.meta['item']

        # parse additional details
        list_span = response.xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'value-chars')]//text()").extract()
        list_a = response.xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'value-chars')]//text()").extract()

        # get additional details from list of <span> tags, element by element
        floor_type = list_span[0].strip()
        num_balcony = list_span[1].strip()
        garage = list_span[2].strip()
        window_type = list_span[3].strip()
        door_type = list_span[4].strip()
        num_window = list_span[5].strip()

        # get additional details from list of <a> tags, element by element
        commission_year = list_a[0].strip()
        num_floors = list_a[1].strip()
        area_sqm = list_a[2].strip()
        floor = list_a[3].strip()
        leasing = list_a[4].strip()
        district = list_a[5].strip()
        address = list_a[6].strip()

        # update item with newly parsed data
        item.update({
            'district': district,
            'address': address,
            'area_sqm': area_sqm,
            'floor': floor,
            'commission_year': commission_year,
            'num_floors': num_floors,
            'num_windows': num_window,
            'num_balcony': num_balcony,
            'floor_type': floor_type,
            'window_type': window_type,
            'door_type': door_type,
            'garage': garage,
            'leasing': leasing
        })
        yield item

        # handling pagination
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'red')]/parent::li/following-sibling::li/a/@href").extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)


# main driver
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(UneguiApartments)
    process.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to move the 'next page' to the parse function. I also just take the 'next page' button value and follow it.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
import unicodecsv as csv
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

dt_today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
file_name = dt_today+' HPI Data'


# Create Spider class
class UneguiApartments(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "unegui_apts"
    allowed_domains = ["www.unegui.mn"]
    custom_settings = {"FEEDS": {f'{file_name}.csv': {'format': 'csv'}}
                       }

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.unegui.mn/l-hdlh/l-hdlh-zarna/oron-suuts-zarna/ulan-bator/']
        for url in urls:
            yield Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        cards = response.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'announcement-container')]")

        # parse details
        for card in cards:
            name = card.xpath(".//a[@itemprop='name']/@content").extract_first()
            price = card.xpath(".//*[@itemprop='price']/@content").extract_first()
            rooms = card.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'announcement-block__breadcrumbs')]/text()").extract_first().split('»')[0].strip()
            link = card.xpath(".//a[@itemprop='url']/@href").extract_first()
            date_block = card.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'announcement-block__date')]/text())").extract_first().split(',')
            date = date_block[0].strip()
            city = date_block[1].strip()

            item = {'name': name,
                    'date': date,
                    'rooms': rooms,
                    'price': price,
                    'city': city,
                    }
            # follow absolute link to scrape deeper level
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'item': item})

        # handling pagination
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "number-list-next js-page-filter number-list-line")]/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # retrieve previously scraped item between callbacks
        item = response.meta['item']

        # parse additional details
        list_span = response.xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'value-chars')]//text()").extract()
        list_a = response.xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'value-chars')]//text()").extract()

        # get additional details from list of <span> tags, element by element
        floor_type = list_span[0].strip()
        num_balcony = list_span[1].strip()
        garage = list_span[2].strip()
        window_type = list_span[3].strip()
        door_type = list_span[4].strip()
        num_window = list_span[5].strip()

        # get additional details from list of <a> tags, element by element
        commission_year = list_a[0].strip()
        num_floors = list_a[1].strip()
        area_sqm = list_a[2].strip()
        floor = list_a[3].strip()
        leasing = list_a[4].strip()
        district = list_a[5].strip()
        address = list_a[6].strip()

        # update item with newly parsed data
        item.update({
            'district': district,
            'address': address,
            'area_sqm': area_sqm,
            'floor': floor,
            'commission_year': commission_year,
            'num_floors': num_floors,
            'num_windows': num_window,
            'num_balcony': num_balcony,
            'floor_type': floor_type,
            'window_type': window_type,
            'door_type': door_type,
            'garage': garage,
            'leasing': leasing
        })
        yield item


# main driver
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(UneguiApartments)
    process.start()
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is a faster method I could employ? I realize this is pretty fast, but I plan to create a spider for each sector from the website (i.e. apartments, land sales, car sales, clothes, etc)

Comment: It depends on the website, but maybe it will be easier to use CrawlSpider, but it's not a guarantee.